# Optimizing a query with multiple cases

Tags: sql

I need some help optimizing this mess of a query below.  The main idea of the query is that I need to run a group of machines( a.group = '3008000204') to find out which ones in the select group do not have the listed applications (app_id) associated with them and I also want to make sure that they aren't part of a separate list of machines(where a.mach_name not IN).

Is there a better way to do this?

```
  SELECT mach_name, costcenter, mach_type, make, model, opsys, firstname, lastname, userid,

    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(select 1 from Workstations f 
    where a.mach_name not IN('WD-KSA699YBK625','WN-MN14GLY8E00U','WN-MN14GLY8E950','WN-MN14GLY8E00R','WN-MNA79GY0V0DM','WN-MNA79GY0V0E2','WN-MNA79GY0V0J4','WN-MNA79GY0V808','WN-MN14GLY8E0J5','WN-MN14GLA66532','WN-MNA79GY0V0E7','WN-MNA79GY0V01D')
        )
            THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no'
    END as dups,

    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Workstations d
        left join Assignments e
        on d.WsID = e.WsID
        where a.mach_Name = d.Mach_Name
        and e.app_id in( 15317,15340,12998,13001,15429)
        )
            THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE 'no'
    END AS readycheck
        FROM Workstations a
        where a.group = '3008000204'
    and ((a.opsys != 'OS X')
    and (a.mach_type != 'V')
    and (a.opsys != 'Windows 10'))
```

Comment: This "question" can be answered on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it's looking to improve working code.

Comment: As a tip, returning 1 or 0 is often more efficient as you can then perform math functions on the results...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using